# How can I add a cancel button to the content add form for a single content type?

Tags: forms

I have several content types on a site and most of them are user-editable but not user-creatable.  However, one content type, **Image**, allows users to upload a picture.  Sometimes, however, users upload the wrong picture and they panic because they don't want that picture to be submitted to the site.

Of course they could always hit the browser's *back* button, but I'd like to add a **Cancel** button for additional assurance.

I found [this thread that gives various solutions for adding cancel buttons on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/133861) as well as [this feature request for adding a cancel button to D8](http://drupal.org/node/116939).  However, there are several different general approaches and I don't know how to limit one to a given content type (in this case, my_image).

Comment: There's a module for that!: http://drupal.org/project/nodeformsettings
... and this module is really fantastic. It's worth to check out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use the following code.

```
function mymodule_form_my_image_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // If the node is being created, redirect the users to the page where
  // they can choose the content type for a new node; otherwise, redirect
  // them to the page showing the node.
  $destination = (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) ? 'node/add' : "node/{$node->nid}";

  $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#markup' => l(t('Cancel'), $destination),
    '#weight' => 20,
  );
}
```

#### Notes

- [markup](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup) is the default form element type; there is no need to use `#type = 'markup'`.
- In the node edit form, all the buttons are inside `$form['actions']`. The weights used from the buttons that form is using are 5 (Save), 10 (Preview), and 15 (Delete). I used 20 to show the link after those buttons, but you can change its weight to show it in a different position.

  ```
  // Add the buttons.
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_REQUIRED || (!form_get_errors() && isset($form_state['node_preview'])), 
    '#value' => t('Save'), 
    '#weight' => 5, 
    '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
  );
  $form['actions']['preview'] = array(
    '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_DISABLED, 
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Preview'), 
    '#weight' => 10, 
    '#submit' => array('node_form_build_preview'),
  );
  if (!empty($node->nid) && node_access('delete', $node)) {
    $form['actions']['delete'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit', 
      '#value' => t('Delete'), 
      '#weight' => 15, 
      '#submit' => array('node_form_delete_submit'),
    );
  }
  ```
- There isn't the need to use `arg()` to understand if the form is for editing an existing node, or for creating a new one. I checked `!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)` is `TRUE`, to verify the node is being created. Drupal seems to simply check `empty($node->nid)`, even though [node_object_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7) uses `!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)`.
- If `$_GET['destination']` is set, the link added with `l()` will point to that path.

Comment: should we have to add the details in the `hook_menu()` when altering a node form(form adding a content type)

Answer (score 7):

Each node form has its own unique id. It's consisted of node type's machine name followed by `_node_form`. So your `my_image` node type's form id is `my_image_node_form`

Here's a mock untested function (D6) to illustrate how to implement:

```
function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $types = array(
    'my_image',
  );

  foreach($types as $type) {
    if($type.'_node_form' == $form_id) {
      if(arg(1) == 'add') {
        // If adding node link to node/add screen
        $link = l(t('Cancel'), 'node/add');
      }
      elseif(arg(2) == 'edit') {
        // If editing node, link to node view screen
        $link = l(t('Cancel'), 'node/'.arg(1));
      }
      $form['cancel'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#value' => $link,
        '#weight' => 0,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

If using Drupal 7 then change `#value` on the array to `#markup`.

Comment: I added this function to my custom module, replaced HOOK with my module's name, changed `my_image` to the machine name of my content type, saved, and cleared the cache twice, but, although Drupal outputs no error, I also don't get a cancel button.  I know you said it's untested code, but I'm unable to figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7? If Drupal 7 then change `#value` on the array to `#markup`

Answer (score 7):

All those solutions are for adding Cancel **link** not a **button**!

If you want to add the button instead of a link you should use this code for module `cancel_button.module`:

```
function cancel_button_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // node types for which Cancel button should be added
    $types = array(
      'biography',
      'faq',
      'draftlaw',
      'vocabulary',
      'draftlaw_page',
      'encyclopedia',
      'user', // if you want to add user's edit form too
    );

    foreach($types as $type) {
        if($type.'_node_form' == $form_id || $type.'_profile_form' == $form_id) {
            $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
                '#type'   => 'submit',
                '#value'  => t('Cancel'),
                '#access' => TRUE,
                '#weight' => 55,
                '#submit' => array('cancel_button_form_cancel', 'node_form_submit_build_node'),
                '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
                );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * cancel_button callback.
     */
    function cancel_button_form_cancel($form, &$form_state) {
        $link = '';
        $path = 'node';
        if('user_profile_form' == $form['#form_id']){
            $path = 'user';
        }
        if(arg(1) == 'add') {
            // If adding entity link to [user|node]/add screen
            $link = $path . '/add';
        }
        elseif(arg(2) == 'edit') {
            // If editing entity, link to node view screen
            $link = $path . '/' . arg(1);
        }
        $url = $_GET['destination'] ? $_GET['destination'] : $link;
        drupal_goto($url);
    }
```

Comment: The link was good enough for me, because I am using CSS to style my buttons anyway, and the link can be styled to look exactly the same way.

Comment: Good. My problem was the same, but with a button. So, maybe someone else likes my solution.

Comment: what's with the `node_form_submit_build_node`?

Comment: Arguably, as "Cancel" is an action with no side effects (it's "idempotent") it should really be a link and not a button. Buttons (certainly in Drupal) typically submit forms via POST, which is intended for non-idempotent requests, so even if the end result is to do nothing they still fire up the server, defeat caches, add to logs etc. Links can always be styled as buttons for consistency.

Comment: Sounds reasonable!

Answer (score 1):

```
function mymodule_form_my_image_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // If the node is being created, redirect the users to the page where
  // they can choose the content type for a new node; otherwise, redirect
  // them to the page showing the node.
  $destination = (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) ? 'node/add' : "node/{$node->nid}";

  $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#markup' => l(t('Cancel'), $destination),
    '#weight' => 20,
  );
}
```