# How can I add a class to a link output via a form?

Tags: forms

Based on [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33677/5147), I'm attempting to add a cancel link.  By default, however, the following code just displays a plain link with no ids and classes.

```
  if(arg(1) == 'add') {
    // If adding node link to node/add screen
    $link = l(t('Cancel'), 'node/add');
  }
  elseif(arg(2) == 'edit') {
    // If editing node, link to node view screen
    $link = l(t('Cancel'), 'node/'.arg(1));
  }
  $form['cancel'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => $link,
    '#weight' => 0,
  );
```

How can I add arbitrary css classes and an id to the link that is output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function:

```
l(t('link_text'), 'path', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('your_class'), 'id' => 'your_id')));
```