# How can I add a class to #markup output?

Tags: theming, hooks

I'm using [this code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/40169/5147) to add a cancel button to my form.  The link is generated through `#markup`:

```
  $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#markup' => l(t('Cancel'), $destination),
    '#weight' => 20,
  );
```

I'd like to add a class, `cancel`, to the link.  I tried adding this line:

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => array('cancel')),
```

but the class is not added.  I'm guessing because `#attributes` cannot modify `#markup`?  How can I add the class in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this...

```
$form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
    '#markup' => l(t('Cancel'), $destination, array('attributes' => array('class' => array('cancel')))),
    '#weight' => 20,
  );
```

The third argument on the 'link' function is for attributes and such...

```
l($text, $path, array $options = array())
```

Documentation: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7

Comment: This is great for that user's case, but would you know a way to make it more general on the form element itself, and not just the link generated? I'm asking because I have a similar issue, but would like to wrap the class around the entire element (#type => 'item') that's using #markup, but according to Drupal's FAPI page, #attributes isn't available for #item.

Comment: Have you tried using #prefix and #suffix? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix

Comment: Yeah, but I was trying to do it without having to add another div; I know, one more div is somewhat inconsequential, but I try to avoid the snowball effect...